# Naming variables in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I'm new to JS and HTML. I learned that it's possible to name a variable by code. So i tried some simple variable naming code. However, it doesn't print anything on the page.

What seems to be the problem?

**javascript**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  window['var' + i] = i;
}
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "" + var8;
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="JScript.js"></script>
    <title>Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><span id="text"></span>left</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user2181397 From the loop.

Comment: @user2181397 - it's a horrible global the OP created in the loop

Comment: it's the variable that is created in   window['var' + i] = i;

Comment: The script comes before the element, move it to right before `</body>`

Comment: @adeneo thanks, it worked. could you tell me why it should be so? for the future

Comment: In simplified terms, elements, including script tags, are read from top to bottom by the browser. When the browser reaches your script, it reads it and parses it, and when your script looks for an element, it can't find that element, because the browser hasn't read that element yet, so it doesn't exist. Hence the script *must* come after the elements it's trying to use, or the script has to wait for an event that tells it that all elements are ready to go etc.

Comment: Just use an object and properties instead of global variables. Your code would work if you placed the script tag just before you close the body tag instead of in the head section. Rule of thumb, unless you can say why the script needs to be in the head section, place it at the end of the body.

Comment: "*I learned that it's possible to name a variable by code*" - **Don't!** Use an array or object instead. Being possible doesn't mean anything about being good practice in a language as dynamic as JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your javascript code in below document.ready function, so that it will execute only when your page is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // enter your code here
});
```

Comment: That's for jQuery, not pure JavaScript (the question has only `javascript` tag).

Comment: The question doesn't mention the tag `jQuery`

Comment: here $ is for jQuery but you can replace it with native Javascript code explained on this link https://gomakethings.com/a-native-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-method/